# Como quitar [ ] de una cadena en Pascal

Tags: pascal

estoy renegando con una funcion para quitar [] de una cadena. Necesito quitar los corchetes de una cadena, pero el problema que tengo, es que esos [] pueden estar en cualquier lugar de la cadena.

el codigo que estoy utilizando es el siguiente:

```
function quitarCorchetes(descripcion: string): String;
Begin
  if descripcion <> '' then
    if descripcion[1] = '[' then
      descripcion := Copy(descripcion,2,Length(descripcion)-2);
  Result := descripcion;
End;
```

Este codigo me sirve para las cadenas que son `"[algo adentro]"`, el problema es cuando la cadena es del tipo `"[algo] mas descripcion"` o `"descripcion [algo]".` No se si hay alguna forma de hacerlo utilizando alguna expresion regular o algo por el estilo. Soy muy nuevo en pascal y no tengo mucha idea.

Comment: No me queda claro si también quieres eliminar el texto que hay dentro de los corchetes o sólo ambos símbolos de la cadena.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function quitarCorchetes(descripcion: string): String;
begin
  for i:=1 to length(descripcion) do
  begin
     if(descripcion[i] = '[') or (descripcion[i] = ']')
     begin
        delete(descripcion, i, 1);
     end;
  end;

  Result:=descripcion;
end;
```

Recorres la cadena mediante un **ciclo for** y por cada posición de la cadena preguntas si se encuentra el caracter **'['** o el caracter **']'**, en caso de encontrarse alguno de esos caracteres pues se borran, de la cadena mediante el **procedimiento Delete**.

**Delete** borra una subcadena dentro de una cadena y recibe **3 parámetros**, el primer parámetro es la cadena, el segundo es la posición de comienzo y el tercer parámetro es la cantidad de caracteres a borrar.

**Ejemplo**:

```
cadena = 'abcdefghi';
delete(cadena, 2, 2);
```

Aquí de la **variable cadena** a partir de la posición **2** se van a borrar **2** caracteres, por tanto el resultado sería **abefghi**, o sea los caracteres c y d fueron borrados de la cadena original.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes valerte de la función `Pos()` para determinar la posición de un caracter dentro de una cadena y, si se encuentra dentro, eliminarlo, por ejemplo, esta función quitará todas las apariciones de un caracter dentro de una cadena:

```
function RemoverTodoCaracter(s: string; Caracter: Char): string;
var
  PosCar: Integer;
begin
  Result := s;
  repeat
    PosCar := Pos(Caracter, Result);
    if PosCar <> 0 then
      Delete(Result, PosCar, 1);
  until PosCar = 0;
end;
```

Podrías, en base a esta, escribir otra rutina para eliminar los corchetes:

```
function RemoverCorchetes(s: string): string;
begin
  Result := RemoverTodoCaracter(s, '[');
  Result := RemoverTodoCaracter(Result, ']');
end;
```

Finalmente, si trabajas con una versión moderna de Pascal (Delphi, FreePascal), puedes valerte de la función `StringReplace`, que se encuentra en la unidad `SysUtils`:

```
function RemoverCorchetes(s: string): string;
begin
  Result := StringReplace(s, '[', '', [rfReplaceAll]);
  Result := StringReplace(Result, ']', '', [rfReplaceAll]);
end;
```